# Replace User Name on one file with User Name plus Company from output of another file

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, data

I have 2 text files. One is the list of user names along with the company they work on the same line but separated by a tab space. The second is a output from a weekly generated report that includes more information.

The goal is to take the name from the weekly report and replace it with the name and company from the list of user names.

List of user names and companies look like this on a UserList.txt file where it is separated by a tab space.

```
Name1      Company 1
Name2      Company 2
Name3      Company 3
Name4      Company 4
Name5      Company 5
```

Weekly output file comes in a Weekly.txt file

[image: test.txt]

I do not know how I can look into the first text file to get the name and company name and replace only that portion on the second text file.

I am looking for the final output to look something like:

[image: FinalOutput.txt]

So far, I found a way to manually do this using the `sed` command. Here is what I have so far:

`sed -r 's/Name1/Name1 Company 1/g;s/Name2/Name2 Company 2/g;s/Name3/Name3 Company 3/g;s/Name4/Name4 Company 4/g;s/Name5/Name5 Company 5/g'`

This works, but it is not reading into another file and pulling the most up to date information. Please keep in mind I am using cygwin and this is all a part of a bigger script.

Comment: You should export your .xlsy file as a .csv file to allow processing by a script. Please do this and add the resulting file and your sample input and output to the question as text, formatted as code blocks using the braces tool `{}` of the editor field. We want to be able to copy and paste your sample data.

Comment: Are there `,` in the Names or Organisations in test.xlsx?

Comment: It does not allow me to copy and paste the output of my csv file for some reason. There are `,` , `.` , and `-` in the company names.

Comment: You can redesign your important data and show us a few lines of your csv file. This way, we can understand what you look for.

Comment: I edited my original post to make it easier because the entire csv process throws me off.

Comment: Are the white spaces between `loginName:` and `Name` spaces or tabs?

Comment: They are `tabs`

Comment: Every section is separated through Tabs. Also on the file with the name and company names, they are separated through tabs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to do the replacement per line in the of the user file. The following script will edit Weekly.txt in-place:

```
prefix="loginName:\s*"
tail -n+2 UserList.txt | while read line; do
    name=$(printf "$line" | cut -f1)
    company=$(printf "$line" | cut -f2 | tr -d '\n')
    sed -i "s/^\($prefix\)$name/\1$name $company/g" Weekly.txt
done
```

To make it more efficent we can collect the replacements and execute sed once:

```
prefix="loginName:\s*"
sedCommand=$(tail -n+2 UserList.txt | while read line; do
    name=$(printf "$line" | cut -f1)
    company=$(printf "$line" | cut -f2 | tr -d '\n')
    printf "s/^\($prefix\)$name/\1$name $company/g;"
done)
sed "$sedCommand" Weekly.txt > new_Weekly.txt
```

This version leaves `Weekly.txt` untouched and writes the result to `new_Weekly.txt`.

Comment: $ in2csv ActiveUsers.xlsx | tail -n+2 | while read line; do     name=$(printf "$line" | csvcut -c 1 | tr -d \");     company=$(printf "$line" | csvcut -c 2 | tr -d \");     printf "s/$name/$name $company/g;" ; done | xargs -I{} sed "{}" LoginExcInternal.txt
-bash: in2csv: command not found

Comment: Is there a way to do it without this? This will be a part of a much larger script. If I have to convert this to a text file instead of using csv, I am willing to do that.

Comment: I converted it into a text file. As of now, the way I did it is that there is the Name, there is a Tab Spacing and then there is the Company Name. It then goes on to the next line for the next User.

Comment: I edited my original post to make it easier because the entire csv process throws me off.

Comment: We are on to something with this:

`prefix="loginName:\s*"
tail -n+2 UserList.txt | while read line; do
    name=$(printf "$line" | cut -f1)
    company=$(printf "$line" | cut -f2)
    sed -i "s/^$prefix$name/$prefix$name $company/g" Weekly.txt
done`

This is pulling the correct information. However, it is overwriting the existing file. I want this to be outputted into a new file while leaving this one alone. Secondly, before the name, it is removing the tab and replacing it with `s*` on every field. Also, after the company name, it should just be a tab, instead it starts a new line.

Comment: I got the `s*` portion figured out. Just had to replace `prefix="loginName:\t"`. I just need to know how to remove adding the extra line after the Company Name and how to do all of this in a new file while leaving the original the way it is.

Comment: Another thing that I noticed is that it pulled up the information for every user except the last one

Comment: You are right about the `\s` part. I did not replace it correctly and posted even another solution that works with any space behind `loginName:`. If you want to keep the original file you have to use the second solution as the first one overwrites the file multiple times. If you ar more comfortable with the first one you would have to make a copy of the file that you can then use.

Comment: I tried the second one but it did not work at all, so i like the output of the first one. Only two things I am trying to figure out now is how to remove the line break after the sed output and why the last name isn't pulling the company name although it is a part of the file with the users and companies.

Comment: I made some changes. Hopefully, both versions work now.

Comment: Is it possible that there are even other characters in the names or company names? E.g., `/`, `"`, `&` and \ would be bad.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90614/discussion-between-ibrahim-a-and-katosh).

Answer (score 2):

Use the `join` command:

```
join -t $'\t' -1 1 -2 2 -o 2.1,1.1,1.2,2.3 \
    user_list.txt \
    <(sed -E 's/^(loginName:)\s+(\S+)\s+(.*)$/\1\t\2\t\3/' test.txt)
```

`join` will join the two tables using column 1 in the first file (`-1 1`) and column 2 in the second file (`-2 2`). It will print the columns in the order specified with `-o`.

In the original version of the question, the user list was in XLSX format. In that case:

```
join -t $'\t' -1 1 -2 2 -o 2.1,1.1,1.2,2.3 \
    <(xlsx2csv -d tab test.xlsx | tail -n +2) \
    <(sed -E 's/^(loginName:)\s+(\S+)\s+(.*)$/\1\t\2\t\3/' test.txt)
```

On Debian, `xlsx2csv` is available as a package (`apt install xlsx2csv`).
`join` is part of the `coreutils` package.

**Edit:** Adjustments to use tab instead of comma as delimiter, and user list in plain text instead of XLSX.

Comment: I edited my original post to make it easier because the entire csv process throws me off.

Comment: You can even get rid of `xlsx2csv` by just using `tail -n+2 UserList.txt`.

Comment: @katosh right. fixed.